# Sonarqube 5.6.3 .sonar /cache directory change

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to do a maven sonar analysis of my project, but the problem I face is, it downloads sonar jars in my users home/user/.sonar directory in Linux.
The logs shows the path to be set in User cache as that of home/user/.sonar
I want to change this patch since this users directory doesn't have enough space.

What all do I need to change?

Comment: Is there a way to change it

Comment: I resolved this issue by putting in Duser.home in mvn cammand for sonar to <new location to download sonar jars in .sonar/cache>

Comment: this is probably a compelling case for a self-answer. Other people who come across this question could be helped by your discovery but may not read the comment thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue by putting in `-Duser.home` in mvn command for sonar
Which would somewhat look like:

`mvn sonar:sonar -Duser.home=__<new location to download sonar jars in which it will create .sonar/cache wherein the jars will be downloaded>__`